# Issues with the memory allocated

Tags: assembly, x86, computer-science, 32-bit, irvine32

I'm new in assembly and learning more all the time. I have a problem that I tried to write back in the days but I'm having some issues with it. I supposed to write a program that dynamically allocates and frees memory from heap memory maintained by the Operating System. The program works but there are issues.  In the main procedure,memory is allocated but the call to free is not quite right.

I like to know how can I add the clear argument pushed to the procedure. so the memory allocated is freed?

This is for assembly x86 32b using the Irvine and the program is running.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc


HANDLE      TEXTEQU <DWORD>


H_ZERO_MEM  EQU    8


GetProcessHeap  PROTO

HeapAlloc       PROTO,  

                hHeap:HANDLE, 

                dwflags: DWORD, 

                dwbytes: DWORD

HeapFree        PROTO,  

                hHeap:HANDLE, 

                dwFlags:DWORD,

                lpMem:DWORD

.data

MSGAlloc    BYTE           " Successfully allocated ",0 

MSGFree     BYTE           " Successfully freed",0      

notAllocMSG BYTE           " Error in allocating. Please try again! ",0

notFreeMSG  BYTE           " There was an error freeing the heap memory",0 

sizeH       DWORD          ?


.code


Alloc       Proc

            push        ebp

            mov         ebp,esp

            INVOKE      GetProcessHeap

            cmp         eax, 0

            je          doNotAlloc

            INVOKE      HeapAlloc, eax, H_ZERO_MEM, [ebp +8] 

doNotAlloc:

            pop         ebp

            ret         4


Alloc       Endp

FREE        proc 

            push            ebp

            mov             ebp,esp

            INVOKE          GetProcessheap

            cmp             eax, 0

            je              doNotFree

            INVOKE          HeapFree , eax, 0, [ebp + 8]

doNotFree:

            pop             ebp

            ret              4

FREE        Endp

main        proc    

            mov              sizeH  , 1024

            mov              eax, sizeH

           push              eax

           call              ALLOC

           cmp               eax, 0

           je                notAlloc

           push              eax

           mov               eax, sizeH 

           call              writedec

           mov               edx, offset MSGAlloc

          call               writestring

          call               crlf  

          call               FREE

          cmp                eax, 0


          je                notHeapFreed

          mov               eax, sizeH 

          call              writedec

          mov               edx, offset MSGFree

          call              writestring

          jmp               endMSG


notAlloc:

          mov               edx, offset notAllocMSG

          call              writestring

          jmp               endMSG

notHeapFreed:

          mov               edx, offset notFreeMSG

          call              writestring

endMSG:
          Exit

main      ENDP

          END               main
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? What is “not quite right” supposed to mean?  Please explain in detail what error you receive.

Comment: I supposed to write a program that dynamically allocates and frees memory from heap memory maintained by the Operating System.  I like to know how can I add the clear argument pushed to the procedure. so the memory allocated is freed? The pogram running but I personally think that I have mistake on main procedure.

Comment: Using HeapAlloc and HeapFree kind of defeats the purpose.  You're just writing thin wrappers around the OS's malloc-like function.  Writing a memory manager gets interesting when you only get memory from the OS in big chunks, like a whole page, so you can't return the memory to the OS until all allocations from that page are freed.  (So you'd maintain a free list of memory that's not in use, but hasn't been handed back to the OS yet.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Can I just remove the HeapFree?